# Non responsive zoom on responsive web

Tags: html, responsive-design

I'm developing the mobile version of a web and the client requested me to allow zooming.

The problem is that in some browsers (like the iexplorer of windows phone or the browser of android) it makes a normal zoom without resizing the window, so the elements simply are viewed bigger, but in other browsers (Safari on ios or chrome on android) it makes a "responsive" zoom, resizing the window and adapting the elements to the new size, changing their positions.

The client has seen this inconsistency and he likes the first type of zoom, so he asked me if i could make this "non responsive" zoom working on all the devices.

I have been researching how to do it but i didn't find anything about the browsers making different zooms or how to avoid the second type of zooming. So if anyone could explain me anything about this i would be very grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your HTML inside the `<head>` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: When I add the maximum-scale=1 to the viewport i can't make zoom in the browsers of the second type that I explained (safari and chrome), but the normal zoom still works on the first browsers. Maybe the normal zooming is a feature of certain browsers?

Comment: Yes sir, it is. For responsive designs we use this maximum-scale and initial-scale so the user see the website according to the design made to fit the device-width. So we prevent bad user experiences surfing your website.